# Passing a js varible to set which view( blade component) has to be loaded

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

When the user clicks in a nav item the content inside a div needs to change asynchronously according to the item clicked, but I dont want to have a route to each one of the item option

as example:

```
<ul>
   <li id="divContentOne"> (each id has the same name of the view, so 
 the first li has to load divContentOne.blade.php)
   </li>
 ...
 ...
 a lot of li
 ...
</ul>

<div id="toload">

</div>
```

*user clicks in first item*

```
 <script> ul.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    Id =  e.target.id;
            asyncFunc();
          });
 </script>
```

*runs async function*

My idea is pass the id to the controller with a post, concac (id . 'blade.php') and return the desired view some how

if you guys have other solution please tell me, thanks

I'm having some strugle to fecth in post method, I'm getting a 419 (unknown status)

My code for now:

```
const reportsMenuBlock = document.getElementsByClassName('reports-menu- 
block');
const reportWrapper = document.getElementById('report-wrapper');

//async function

function makeRequest() {
  const token = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content;
  url = '/reports/asyncPost';

  fetch(url,{
    method: 'POST',
    credentials: 'omit',
    mode: 'same-origin',
    headers:{
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        "X-CSRF-TOKEN": token
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(reportId)
    });
  } 



// take the id of the item menu clicked and calls the async function

for(i = 0; i < reportsMenuBlock.length; i++){
 reportsMenuBlock[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    reportId =  e.target.id;
    makeRequest();
});
};
```

My route:

```
Route::post('/reports/asyncPost', 'ViewController@asyncReports')- 
>name('asyncReports');
```

My controller:

```
  public function asyncReports()
{
    $dados = $Request;
}
```

Comment: Your solution seems nice to me. Why did you not already try it? Was it your issue?

Comment: I edit the post with more details

Comment: Your controller's method does nothing. It should return the view's HTML you want. Then, after reading [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) documentation, it seems to me that it is missing `then((response) => {...})`.